# What is the maximum size of signed long long data type in 32 bit Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++, gcc4

I am trying to run the below program in 32 bit Linux platform.

```
    int main()
    {
         unsigned long long  val  = 0;
         val   = 140417 * 100000 + 92 + 1;
    }
```

The output is some garbage value (1156798205).

After some research, I found that :[here](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/zsync-windows/wiki/Types_sizes/print)

```
 long long size: 64 bits (MAX VALUE: signed long long = 144115188075855871, unsigned long long = 1073741823)
```

The above code is giving the same problem with Visual Studio 2005 for both the datatypes unsigned long long and signed long long.

But as per the MSDN documentation:
 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
unsigned long long  8 byte  range of values  0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

I am wondering how to handle large range of values in 32 bit Linux platform using the C++ program.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()`. Note that `long long` is only guaranteed to be 64 bits since C++11 (in C++, that is.)

Comment: @juanchopanza, The call std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max(); returns a large value. but the above code is not working. I think I didn't understand your comment completely

Comment: That code will not output anything at all...

Comment: I believe *visual-c++* does not run on Linux. You might have mistagged your question.

Comment: BTW, your program does not perform any output: it is lacking a call to some output function like `printf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that although you are using a 64bit data type, your calculations are using 32bit values, so you are encountering integer overflow.  `140417 * 100000` is 14041700000 (0x344F356A0) in 64bit, but is 1156798112 (0x44F356A0) in 32bit.  As you can see, 0x300000000 is being truncated off of the result, as it does not fit in a 32bit value.

You need to ensure that you are using 64bit calculations, eg:

```
typedef unsigned long long ulong64_t;

int main()
{
     ulong64_t val = 0;
     val = ulong64_t(140417) * ulong64_t(100000) + 92 + 1;
}
```

Alternatively, use integer constant suffixes:

```
int main()
{
     unsigned long long val = 0;
     val = 140417i64 * 100000i64 + 92 + 1;
}
```

Or:

```
int main()
{
     unsigned long long val = 0;
     val = 140417ull * 100000ull + 92 + 1;
}
```

Comment: looks great, let me test it.

Comment: The `i64` suffix is non-standard.

Comment: True, which is why I provided `ull` as well. `i64` does exist in VC++, though.  Of course, if you want to write portable code, you can't really use constant suffixes at all, since different compilers use different suffixes and they cannot be easily abstracted away using precompiler macros. So use the type-cast method instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the type of an unsuffixed integer constant (like `42`) is the smallest of `int`, `long int`, `long long int` that can hold its value, and the type of an expression is determined by the expression itself, not by the context in which it appears.

So if `int` happens to be 32 bits on your system, then in this:

unsigned long long val = 140417 * 100000 + 92 + 1;

the constants `140417` and `100000` (which both fit in 32 bits) are of type `int`, and the multiplication is a 32-bit multiplication -- which overflows because the product of those two numbers doesn't fit in 32 bits. (The type of a standalone literal is adjusted based on its value; the type of a larger expression is not.)

The most straightforward way to avoid this is to use constants of type `unsigned long long`:

```
unsigned long long val = 140417ULL * 100000ULL + 92ULL + 1ULL;
```

(It happens that not all the `ULL` suffixes are necessary, but it doesn't hurt to apply them to all the constants in the expression.)

Answer (score 0):

If you print out: `sizeof(unsigned long long)`, the max is 2^(that value)-1.

Comment: No, use `<limits.h>` (in C) or  `<climits>` or `std::numeric_limits` (in C++11)

Comment: It would actually be `2^(sizeof(unsigned long long) * 8) - 1` on most modern systems, which just highlights the fact that you should use the predefined constants as suggested by @BasileStarynkevitch , rather than trying to code them yourself...

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering how to handle large range of values in 32 bit Linux platform using the C++ program.

Add `#include <stdint.h>` and use explicit `long long` or preferably `int64_t` or `uint64_t` types.

Recent GCC (e.g. GCC 4.9 which is released now in mid-april 2014) may have `__int128`.

If you want to handle very large numbers (bigger than 2<sup>63</sup> in absolute value), so called [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) you'll need a bignum library (like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)), or a language supporting them natively (e.g. Common Lisp, using [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) ....)

BTW, the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
  unsigned long long val = 0;
  val = 140417 * 100000LL + 92 + 1;
  printf ("val=%lld\n", val);
  return 0;
}
```

does work as you expect on Linux x86 32 bits. If you omit the `LL` suffix for `100000` (suffix `LL` needed to get a `long long` literal 100000 constant) you'll get a warning `integer overflow in expression`at *compile* time with `gcc -Wall hpfe.c -o hpfe` ....